# Vue - How to render $slots.default in a div to calculate its height?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to simplify my problem:

Let us say I have a modal component

```
//example.php
<modal>
  <div>A big div</div>
</modal>
```

Before the modal is shown I need to calculate the height for the proper animation. Inside the modal Vue it looks like this:

```
   //Modal.vue
   ...
   <transition
      :name="transition"
      @before-enter="beforeTransitionEnter"
      @after-leave="afterTransitionLeave"
    >
      <div
        v-if="visibility.modal"
        ref="modal"
        class="v--modal v--modal-box"
        :style="modalStyle"
      >
        <slot/>

      </div>
    </transition>
```

I know that with this.$slots.default I get the node of the slot. 
But I'm not sure how I can create a div, add the node to the div so that I can then calculate the height of it?

**Edit:** 
Is it possible to call your own render function so I can use it like in the docs?

```
render: function (createElement) {
  // `<div><slot></slot></div>`
  return createElement('div', this.$slots.default)
}
```

Like

```
  guessSlotsHeight(){

  let modalDiv = document.createElement('div')

  modalDiv.className = 'v--modal v--modal-box'

  //something like
  let slotDiv = this.render('div', this.$slots.default)
  modalDiv.appendChild(slotDiv);
},
```

Comment: I need this only once for init. After that, I calculate the height with `this.$refs.modal.getBoundingClientRect().height`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is too complex. It's easiest than you think.

Look, animation is the thing which happens to DOM. Therefore, DOM is available when animation starts. So, you can access any DOM element using Vue `ref` (recommended) or native javascript syntax in `mounted` hook. And there you can take the element height or any other property you want and store in in your `data` (for example).

### Possible solution example #1

Vue transition `before-enter` event function has the target element as an argument by default. So, you can get the modal height in your `beforeTransitionEnter`  function:

#### Modal.vue

```
data() {
   return {
      modalHeight: 0,
      visibility: {
         modal: false
      }
   }
},

methods: {
   beforeTransitionEnter(element) {
     this.modalHeight = element.offsetHeight;
   }
}
```

### Possible solution example #2

For this example there is one important detail. I see in your code example that you display the next div conditionally:

```
`<div v-if="visibility.modal" class="v--modal v--modal-box">`
```

Be careful with that, as I don't know what is the init value of `visibility.modal`.

I would use `watch` feature to know content height every time once `visibility.modal` gets `true` in this particular case.

Look at the example. It's based on the code which you provided and it's a possible solution in your case.

#### Modal.vue

```
data() {
   return {
      isMounted: false,
      modalHeight: 0,
      visibility: {
         modal: false
      }
   }
},

mounted() {
   this.isMounted = true;
},

watch: {
  visibility: {
     handler(value) {
       if (value.modal && this.isMounted) {
         this.modalHeight = this.$refs.modal.clientHeight;
       }
     },
     deep: true
  }
}
```

As you can see - you will always have actual `modalHeight` value and you can use it whenever you want within the `Modal.vue` component.